# Changing css class at page level

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

This code was working at component level, but when `nuxt-child` and `nuxt-link` is used instead of button, it changes the page, but the color remains the same. Do you know how this can be fixed?

```
<nuxt-link to="/head" :class="headButtonMode" @click="setSelectedTab('head-page')">
</nuxt-link>

<nuxt-link to="/" :class="mainButtonMode" @click="setSelectedTab('main-page')">
</nuxt-link>

<nuxt-child />

data() {
    return {
      selectedTab: "main-page",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    headButtonMode() {
      return this.selectedTab === "head-page" ? "head flat" : "head";
    },
    mainButtonMode() {
      return this.selectedTab === "main-page" ? "main flat" : "main";
    },
  },
  methods: {
    setSelectedTab(tab) {
      this.selectedTab = tab;
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like:

```html
<button @click="setSelectedTab('main-page'); $router.push({path:'/head'})" :class="headButtonMode"> 
</button>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Hey mate, did you try to replace yours nuxt-link `<nuxt-link to="/head" :class="headButtonMode" @click="setSelectedTab('head-page')">
</nuxt-link>` with one from my answer

Comment: It broke the code and to=/head is not working